# Check if selector is defined

Tags: jquery

I have the following plot function:

```
function plot(selector, data) {
  var context = selector.get(0).getContext("2d");
  var wrapper = $(selector).parent();
}
```

And on my javascript main file I have the following:

```
plot($('#pageviews'), data);
```

In some pages I do not the pageviews item so I get the error: 
TypeError: selector.get(...) is undefined

How can I check, inside the plot function, if the selector is defined?

And if it is undefined just exit the plot function.

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: This question get a lot of same answers at within few seconds..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to check selector exists or not:

```
if (selector.length > 0){
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use length property:

```
if ( 0 < selector.length )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if(selector.length > 0) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

## It's an Array.

Since the selector retrns an array of selected elements , Check the `length`.You can use this

```
if ($('#pageviews').length >0 ) {
    //call plot
}
```

or even

```
if( $('#pageviews').get(0) ) {    
//call plot
}
```

Comment: No, it is not an array! jQuery objects are array-like, but they aren't real arrays as - for example - `[]` is one.

Answer (score 2):

You can check length

```
if (selector.length > 0){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function plot(selector, data) {
  if (!!selector.length) {
    // no element was found
  }

  var context = selector.get(0).getContext("2d");
  var wrapper = $(selector).parent();
}
```

This checks whether the jQuery result object does contain any elements.